# Knee bend off about 30 degrees from pole target

Tags: rigging

[image]I searched but didn’t find this specific problem. I am trying to create a very basic rig for a low poly character. I am using FK for everything except the legs and feet. I have built several different rigs and always have the same problem. When I bend the characters knee it bends outward making it look bow legged. I am adjusting the knee to be aligned with the pole target as suggested but it seems to be bending about 30 degrees off. I have also tried aligning all of the bones axis with no luck. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: We need to see an image of the problem which you can create via Window > Save Screenshot in Blender and add into your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post. It would also be good if you could share a Blend file which is demonstrating the problem via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page.

Comment: Thanks… I will upload those tonight.

Comment: Move the knee joints forward further towards the knee cap in side view. I know you have a slight bend at the knee already but it isn't sufficient by the look of it.

Comment: Ok, Thanks John.